# Flutter MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

(on linux app)I get this error when trying to sign in using firebase auth,
running the app with F5 directly crashes it and the error was like this first: `MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel $name');`

after closing the app and running it again with flutter run error turned to this : `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)`

I tried flutter clean and flutter run again, it didn't work. everything is imported and installed I'm sure.

Error appeared after this function:

```
void signUserIn() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text,
      password: passwordController.text,
    );
  }
```

I also get these errors:

```
 [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Auth#registerIdTokenListener on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:313:7)
<asynchronous suspension>

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Auth#registerAuthStateListener on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:313:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried flutter clean and flutter run again. Didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps reinstalling the firebase_auth package fix this issue. From here it just seems like flutter isn't properly recognizing this package

Comment: Installed firebase_auth again, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you are working in a Linux Platform,

The

> firebase_auth 4.3.0

Doesn't supports Linux.
Try running the app in different environment, such as a Linux virtual machine or a different Linux distribution, to see if the issue is specific to your current environment.
OR
you may want to seek help from the Flutter or Firebase communities or consult the documentation for the package you're using to see if there are any known issues or solutions.

EDITED

I found this Package that supports both Linux and Windows

[Firebase_auth_desktop](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_desktop)

Comment: I tried passing web config if platform is linux or windows as well, but this didn't work either. But i didn't try this on windows yet. Looking at the package website windows isn't listed as well, are there no options to use firebase auth and database on desktop ?

Comment: Here is your solution, Try this package. It has both LINUX as well as Windows, [https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_desktop]